# android studio: Automatic push/organize button when click

Tags: java, android, button

I'm currently working on a small project for my semester when I run into a problem while designing the figma, preparing for implementation.
The problem is simple, that when the user presses one of the 4 buttons, the button pressed will be pushed up and if the user presses it again to cancel, it will return to the original position.

Image example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiOBL.jpg

I did try using 3 listview for this question, 2 contain other buttons and 1 only appear when  there is a button been pressed but fail due to my lack of knowledge and to confess it confuse me a lot.

So i am really gratefull if someone can help me with this, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well after a few days and more research i find a way to help me get what I want. It's actually funny, it's also quite simple.

What you need is to call the layout containing the button, remove the child view (button) from that layout and add another layout.

first you create 2 layouts in xml, in my case i need 3:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/men"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Mens"
            ></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/women"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Womens"
            ></Button>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/boys"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Boys"
            ></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/girl"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Girls"
            ></Button>

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

after that you call and use the removeView, addView:

```
    package com.example.pushbutton;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button men,women,boy,girl;
    LinearLayout one,two;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        men = findViewById(R.id.men);
        women = findViewById(R.id.women);
        boy = findViewById(R.id.boys);
        girl = findViewById(R.id.girl);
        one = findViewById(R.id.one);
        two = findViewById(R.id.two);

        men.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                two.removeView(men);
                one.addView(men);
            }
        });

    }
    }
```